# What command to use to print contents of a double pointer using gdb?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have

```
int var = 0 , *p = &var;
```

I want to print on GDB the value `0` using `p`

I tried

```
x /s p
```

It is not working.

And similarly I want to do it with a double pointer

```
void **args
```

Comment: Have you tried *dereferencing* e.g. `p`? Like `print *p`?

Comment: yes thanks that works

Comment: What about  `p *args`?

Answer (score 1):

`print *p` should work. I'm not sure what you want to do with double pointer `args`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `p` is a pointer to `int`, you should print `*p` to print the value which `p` is pointing to.